# How to stop XBox Music commercials while playing music in collection?

Tags: windows-8, mp3, xbox-music

So i decided to give Xbox Music a try, and played a song in my collection. Then moved to another song and a **commercial** started playing. Huh? Searching revealed [others with this problem](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/3144/p/368516/1894855.aspx), but i didn't see any answers.

Yes, i know [Xbox Music plays commercials when streaming free music that you don't own](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/music-and-video/music/ads-while-streaming), but this is mp3 music i own, on my hard drive, in my collection. MS claims *"You’ll never get ads when you’re playing MP3s that are on your PC or when you’re playing music you bought from Xbox Music."*

(FWIW, this is running on Windows 8.1 Pro, though the problem seems to have been reported last year too, so it's probably not a new issue.)